# Changing Time Format In PHP

Tags: php, regex, datetime, time

I got the following Output from SQL Table with varchar datatype.

```
Monday,11th of August 2014
```

I want to display as

```
11-Aug-2014
```

I want to show the above date format for all the dates comming from SQL But mysql is giving me in a large format.
I am new with PHP
any one here who can make this possible with PHP code.

```
If Possible Provide me Regex to solve this.
```

I simple want to disply the shortten formate of Date.

i have Varchar as my SQL so, its Not possible with Date_Time function to solve it.

Comment: What datatype is your column in the MySQL table? If you're storing it in that format as a varchar rather than using the native date/time datatypes, then you should change your database first

Comment: Then I highly recommend that you change your database first: use MySQL native [date/time datatypes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-types.html) for dates

Comment: We can use regex to get the desired output.

Comment: You can mess about a lot and don't even need to use regexp (DateTime::createFromFormat() would be better than regexp), but the fact remains that as long as you're storing strings in a varchar, you're making life more difficult for yourself, and adding more and more workrounds to solve problems that shouldn't even exist if you'd used the correct datatype.... the longer you delay fixing the underlying problem, the more effort it will take, and the more problems you'll have in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a regex solution, **however** I recommend that you listen to all the comments you have received about the datatype of your column.

```
$str = "Monday,11th of August 2014"; 

preg_match("/\,\s*(\d+).+([A-Z][a-z]{2}).+(\d{4})/", $str, $date); 
echo $date[1]."-".$date[2]."-".$date[3];
```

Output:

```
11-Aug-2014
```

Comment: Thanks This will Safe My Life.
Thanks a Lot :)

Comment: You are welcome, just remember the `however`, it is recommended that you change the datatype of the field :)

Comment: It may save your life now, but always remember the axiom that the next person to work with your code will be an axe-wielding psychopath who knows where you live

Comment: Yaa Thanks for the suggestions.
i will change the datatype as soon as possible :)

Answer (score 0):

`select date_format(mdate, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AS formated_date from tabl;` in mysql or same thing you can do in php.

```
$timestamp = strtotime($row["mdate"]);
then you can use all options of date() to format it, for example:

echo date('j-F-Y', $timestamp); // returns 09-03-2010 16:59:18 this can be set as per your required formate.
```

where mdate is your field in database for date.

Comment: The above not possible because i dont have time in my Varchar SQL field.

Comment: then you should set datatype to date/time in your mysql it will solve your problem and will be good too.

Answer (score -1):

This Link will help you alot.

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

```
$date = new DateTime($YourDate);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Greetings

Comment: Links only answers are not considered as good answers as the link or the content could change.

Comment: @Webice, please provide an example of how the function would be used instead of just a link to the german version of the manual.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d-%b-%Y') FROM dual
```

Instead of `NOW()` you can use your date column, instead of `dual` your table.

This requires a column type of `DATETIME`.

A full table of date format options can be found here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: I have varchar as a datatype.

Comment: @Sidj you should change it as Mark Baker already suggested, it's easier, sometimes faster and more reliable to work with semantical correct types.

Comment: But changing datatype all my other php codes get wrong.
as i have more than 5 Lakhs Entrys.
If it is possible provide me Regex to solve this :)

Comment: Fix it now, or simply create more and more problems for yourself in the future: what's going to happen the first time you need to apply a SQL ORDER BY on that column?

Comment: @Sidj create a new table with the same structure but fixed types, use `INSERT INTO .... SELECT` insert from old table into new table with fixed types. = no data loss, no risk

Comment: That wont work on a varchar column, read the question.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Look at the edit history of the question and the time of my answer......

Comment: Yes, but the guy has no intention of changing the column type, he is either to far into the development or to lazy or to stupid or making some minor fix to someone elses code on a budget that does not allow him to fix all the bad code he has found. Added the last OR to be generous.

Comment: And now you want me to delete my answer? Feel free to flag it.

Answer (score -1):

You could solve this without the use of anything external to the MySQL query.

Using the STR_TO_DATE() function in the query that returns the date from the table, like so :-

```
SELECT stupid_varchar_date, 
       STR_TO_DATE(stupid_varchar_date,'%W,%D of %M %Y') as a_usable_date
```

You could also take the Very Good Advice given by others and fix the table by creating a new column in this table and updating the table using the stupid_varchar_date to calc a proper MySQL date or date/time field.

```
UPDATE table SET new_date = STR_TO_DATE(stupid_varchar_date,'%W,%D of %M %Y')
```